# Alerta al enviar mensaje

Tags: php, email

Sucede que estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario de contacto para mi sitio, ya tengo casi todo terminado, sin embargo quiero que al momento de presionar el botón enviar en lugar que me envíe a otra pagina, solo muestre una alerta diciendo que el mensaje ya se envío.

```
<?php

    $destino = "******************";
    $nombre = $_POST["Nombre"];
    $telefono = $_POST["Telefono"];
    $correo = $_POSTO["Correo"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["Mensaje"];

    $contenido = "Nombre: ".$nombre. "\nTelefono: " .$telefono. "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;
    mail($destino, "Cotizacion", $contenido);
    header("Location: index.html");

?>
```

Este es mi código en php actual.

Comment: Te falta poner el código php ;)

Comment: ya lo agregue ;)

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo es con ajax, en el submit del form, realiza la petición ajax y cancela la propagación de eventos. Luego en la parte success o done del ajax, realiza el resto de acciones como mostrar un error o no.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso la línea `header("Location: index.html");` efectivamente te redirige a otra página. Si quieres quedarte en la misma página debes quitar esa línea.

También, puedes verificar si no hay error en el envío del mensaje, algo así:

```
<?php

    $destino = "******************";
    $nombre = $_POST["Nombre"];
    $telefono = $_POST["Telefono"];
    $correo = $_POSTO["Correo"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["Mensaje"];

    $contenido = "Nombre: ".$nombre. "\nTelefono: " .$telefono. "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;
    $resultado=mail($destino, "Cotizacion", $contenido);

    if($resultado){
        echo "Mensaje enviado con éxito";
    }else{
        echo "Hubo un error enviando el mensaje";
    }
    //header("Location: index.html");

?>
```

Comment: Entendido @HugoCostilla. Aunque si quieres hacerlo de una forma más elegante, sin que te recargue la página al dar click en el botón, puedes usar Ajax, como ha comentado track3r.  De ese modo, por Ajax, envías los datos recogidos en el formulario, haces el intento de envío del mensaje y en un contenedor de la propia página muestras el mensaje de éxito o de error, según el caso. De hecho, ya los formularios modales, las alertas, etc, van cayendo en desuso, se consideran una *mala experiencia de usuario*, en el sentido de que te obligan a interactuar con el programa de forma innecesaria.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$destino = "******************";
$nombre = $_POST["Nombre"];
$telefono = $_POST["Telefono"];
$correo = $_POSTO["Correo"];
$mensaje = $_POST["Mensaje"];

$contenido = "Nombre: ".$nombre. "\nTelefono: " .$telefono. "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;
$resultado = mail($destino, "Cotizacion", $contenido);

if($resultado == true){
  echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Su mensaje ha sido enviado")<script>';
}else {
  echo echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error al mandar mensaje")<script>';
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Mi codigo actual es de esta forma, en la condicion mande el alert con javascript